# VB.NET Screen Capture

Tags: vb.net, screen-capture

Hello all i am using the below code to capture the screenshot of the black panel of my window form in visual basic 2005.

My problem is that I want the red border image to come in between and to be full.

[image]

My code :

```
    Dim bounds As Rectangle  
    Dim screenshot As System.Drawing.Bitmap  
    Dim graph As Graphics  
    bounds = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds  
    screenshot = New System.Drawing.Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb)  
    graph = Graphics.FromImage(screenshot)  
    graph.CopyFromScreen(618, 191, 850, 455, bounds.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy)  
    screenshot.Save("d:\\dcap.bmp", Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp)  `
```

[image]

Comment: `I want the red border image to come in between` in between **WHAT**?

Comment: Is there meant to be a video image in there?

Comment: the image in the red border should be covering whole screen not just occuping that corner

Comment: Is the video being shown in your own program, or in a third-party program? If the former, what are you using to show it, and if the latter you should find out if there is an API which lets you get a still image from it.

Comment: Hi Andrew Im using Directshowlib for showing video in that panel but at the time of taking the above screenshot the video was not running can u help me bro as it is a part of my major project..thanx in advance

Comment: if you are using directshow, why not do a frame capture?

Comment: @Plutonix can you give me a link from where i can get info about it.

Comment: no because it very much depends on how you built your graph.  VMR9, SampleGrabber, MediaDetector and BasicVideo all do it a little differently.  The DS Lib has several sample though with one in VB

Answer (score 4):

Your code works well just set the bounds to zero

```
 Dim bounds As Rectangle
    Dim screenshot As System.Drawing.Bitmap
    Dim graph As Graphics
    bounds = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds
    screenshot = New System.Drawing.Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb)
    graph = Graphics.FromImage(screenshot)
    graph.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, bounds.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy)
    screenshot.Save("d:\\dcap.jpg", Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp)
```