# VB.NET Screenshot Application Window and Send

Tags: vb.net

I have built an application that obtains details from a web service and displays them in a GUI for the agent to see.

I've had instances of problems occuring, sometimes an exception due to a change in how the data is received due to the provider and unfortunately no user lets me know this occurs, they just click through and pay no attention to the error.

I've built a custom form to capture the error and then email it to me with some details like username etc. etc.

I would ideally LIKE to capture the screen of the application as well, much like an ALT+PRINTSCRN so I can see what the application looks like at the time of error as well.

How possible is this?

Comment: Isn't [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21263096/vb-net-screen-capture) what you are looking for ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `WinForm`, I've done this before:

```
Public Sub SaveAsImage(frm As Form)
        'Dim fileName As String = "sth.png"
        'define fileName
        Dim format As ImageFormat = ImageFormat.Png
        Dim image = New Bitmap(frm.Width, frm.Height)
        Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(image)
            g.CopyFromScreen(frm.Location, New Point(0, 0), frm.Size)
        End Using
        image.Save(fileName, format)
End Sub
```

When being called, it will capture the current screen in the area defined by `frm` and save to a file.